# Android Preferences - change font size by user

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am looking for a solution for my app to let the user select the font size via settings menu. Like I am able to do in other apps e.g. Jota+. Here are some screen shots for a better understanding (sorry - my Jota+ is a German version):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As of now I installed already a settingsActivity which is using a FragmentManager to call a PreferenceFragment using my pref_main.xml as resource.

Any idea how I can archive this?

My SettingsActivity:

```
    package com.wbapps.wbshoppinglist;

/**
 * Created by Andreas on 2/15/2018.
 */

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
    private static final String TAG = SettingsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // load settings fragment
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MainPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    /**
     * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
     * to reflect its new value.
     */
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            String stringValue = newValue.toString();

            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
                // the preference's 'entries' list.
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

                // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                preference.setSummary(
                        index >= 0
                                ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                : null);

            }

            else if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
                if (preference.getKey().equals("key_gallery_name")) {
                    // update the changed gallery name to summary filed
                    preference.setSummary(stringValue);
                }
            } else {
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

}
```

My AppCompatPreferenceActivity:

```
package com.wbapps.wbshoppinglist;

/**
 * Created by Andreas on 2/15/2018.
 */

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A {@link PreferenceActivity} which implements and proxies the necessary calls
 * to be used with AppCompat.
 */
public abstract class AppCompatPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private AppCompatDelegate mDelegate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDelegate().installViewFactory();
        getDelegate().onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getDelegate().onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
        return getDelegate().getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public void setSupportActionBar(@Nullable Toolbar toolbar) {
        getDelegate().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
        return getDelegate().getMenuInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().setContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void addContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        getDelegate().addContentView(view, params);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        getDelegate().onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTitleChanged(CharSequence title, int color) {
        super.onTitleChanged(title, color);
        getDelegate().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        getDelegate().onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getDelegate().onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getDelegate().onDestroy();
    }

    public void invalidateOptionsMenu() {
        getDelegate().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private AppCompatDelegate getDelegate() {
        if (mDelegate == null) {
            mDelegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, null);
        }
        return mDelegate;
    }
}
```

My pref_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_header_font_setting">
        <Preference
            android:summary="@string/pref_font_setting"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_header_about">

        <Preference
            android:selectable="false"
            android:summary="@string/summary_about" />

        <Preference
            android:summary="@string/app_version"
            android:title="@string/title_version" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here you can see the project structure:
[image]
[image]

Many thanks
Andreas

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking how to save the preference?

Comment: @Amjad Khan - Sorry, but I can not see how this page you mentioned will help me with my problem

Comment: @Joel Nieman - Yes I think if a user change the font-size he will have it permanently. So it might be a good idea to save the preference also

Comment: @Amjad Khan Why was it uncleared yesterday that I use preferences? I was writing about preferences in my post. And my problem is not how to store some user input. I know about db or shared preferences. I was asking how to use the Android API for a user gui preferences to create a list for changeing text size. Sorry if that was not clear enough. Therefore I posted the example of the Jota+ app. I looked already e.g. the Android developer guide for settings but was unable to find out how to use Android's Preference APIs for my issue.